# Avoid duplicate interface definition for class MagicalRecord.h

Tags: xcode7, magicalrecord

When I go to call:

`enableShorthandMethods` from the file `"MagicalRecord+ShorthandMethods.h"`using :

```
#import <MagicalRecord/MagicalRecord+ShorthandMethods.h>
there is an error:
Duplicate interace definition for class MagicalRecord.
```

I'm getting:

> `duplicate interface definition for class MagicalRecord.h`

MR has been added with `cocoaPods`.

```
pod 'MagicalRecord'
pod 'MagicalRecord/ShorthandMethodAliases'
```

I tried to follow the following guide:
https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/master/Docs/Installing-MagicalRecord.md

To no avail.

Answer (score 0):

After running 
'find . -iname "MagicalRecord.h"'

There was a remaining copy of the file from the previous non-pods installation.  The got rid of this very message.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was something to do with an XCode5 project using ARC.  Setting a flag for no ARC fixed the problem.  An object associated with the MR was involved.